# Probability that the sample contains no more than 2 black balls

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A box contains 18 balls. 6 are black and 12 are white. A sample of 4 balls are taken with replacement, what is the probability that the sample contains no more than 2 black balls

I would really appreciate the help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the sample contains no more than $2$ black balls is the probability that it contains $0, 1, $or $2$ black balls.

The probability that the sample contains no black balls is 
$$\left(\frac{12}{18}\right)^{4}$$
The probability that the sample contains one black ball is 
$$4\cdot \frac{6}{18}\cdot \left(\frac{12}{18}\right)^{3}$$
since there are $4$ orderings of the sample, and we need to draw one black ball and three white ones. Using this logic, can you find the probability that the sample contains two black balls? Once you have that, you are done.

Comment: You didn't account for the replacement.

Comment: @Raghav yes I did. Without replacement, the probability of selecting no black balls would be $\frac{12}{18}\frac{11}{17}\frac{10}{16}\frac{9}{15}$

Comment: You are saying the opposite, without replacement the probability of selecting no black balls will be $(\frac{12}{18})^3$.

Comment: Replacement means that after you select a ball, you put it back. That means each time you select a ball, there are $18$ to choose from. Without replacement means that once you select a ball, it is gone, so for the second draw there will be $17$ left, etc.

Comment: Ohh shi , my bad. Got confused.